# How to hide technologies stack from third party website to know our web site development?

Tags: security, server, webserver, web-deployment, godaddy-api

I have created one website in .Net Core(v3.1) and host it into a Godaddy server and web application works fine but I want to hide my technology stacks like Bootstrap, jQuery, and any other technologies that I have used?

Is there any possible way to do that if anyone has an idea about that it would be appreciated?

Comment: You can't, and there wouldn't be any point anyway. Nobody cares.

Comment: Actually, there is some serious issue with technical detail is disclosed so I have to hide it.